# How to evaluate algebraic expressions in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am making my first andriod app in whicg user will input the algebric equation then the respective code must Integrate that equation and then it should generate a table by putting some numerical values. Now I am confused how to differentiate that equation and how to substitute values like in python sympy I can use subs method so in java what how to do that?

Comment: please post: 1) example; 2) desired output; 3) code which you tried for the task; 4) output of this code with explaination how it differs from desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is an android project that simplify all form of Boolean expression.This project use all the algebraic boolean expression in simplification of the expression.

[The 12 Rules of Boolean Algebra](https://github.com/superibk/BloleanAlgebraicSimplifier)